# Is there a way to make an Xcode template that generates a View-Controller pair?

Tags: swift, xcode

I often use this pattern when creating `UIViewController`/`UIView` pairs. It would be nice if I could define a template in Xcode so that I could click New File -> [template] and generate a `MyViewController.swift` and `MyView.swift` like in the example below.

MyViewController.swift

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        self.view = MyView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}

extension MyViewController : MyViewDelegate
{
    // Provide data, pop off a navigation stack, etc
}
```

MyView.swift

```
protocol MyViewDelegate : class {
}

class MyView: UIView
{
    weak var delegate : MyViewDelegate?

    // MARK: - Initialization

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup()
    {
        // Configure views

        // Assemble

    }
}
```